# SequelizeHostNotFoundError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND [hostname] when running Dockerized application

Tags: node.js, dockerfile, sequelize.js

I am encountering an error SequelizeHostNotFoundError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND [hostname] when trying to connect to a PostgreSQL database using Sequelize in my Node.js application. Here are the details of my setup:

I have a Docker container running PostgreSQL with the name "[container-name]".
I have defined a Sequelize instance with the following configuration:

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize('postgres', 'postgres', 'mysecretpassword', {
  host: '[hostname]', // Replace with the actual hostname or container name
  dialect: 'postgres',
});
```

The strange thing is that the script works correctly when running the application without Docker, but I encounter the SequelizeHostNotFoundError when running it within a Docker container. I have ensured that the Docker container is in the same network as the database.

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue and successfully connect to the PostgreSQL database from within the Docker container. Thank you.

I have also verified that the database container is running and accessible by testing the connection using tools like psql or database clients.